# Obtaining GPS & Internet together with Waveshare GSM/GPRS/GNSS HAT module

Tags: pi-3, internet, uart, gps

I'm using Stretch installed Raspberry Pi 3 B and Waveshare GSM/GPRS/GNSS HAT to obtain GPS real-time location and internet.

What I have done :

- Used USB-UART interface and connected jumper
- Using Python 3 & obtained location details successfully
- For internet - followed https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/SIM868_PPP_Dail-up_Networking this and able to connect internet  (ttyUSB0 was used)> **But the connection is very slow (always ping succeeded) I was not able to activate the 3G connection though I update with APN of the service provider.**

What I expect :

- A method of obtaining GPS location while having internet at the same time from this module.
- To activate the 3G connection using this module.

Any suggestion, please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Question***

> Rpi3V Stretch and Waveshare GSM/GPRS/GNSS HAT for GPS an Internet.
>
> Used USB-UART and Python 3 location OK
>
> SIM868_PPP_Dail-up_Networking ttyUSB0 connection ***very slow***
>
> Not able to do ***3G*** connection though I update with APN of the service
>   provider.

***Answer***

Well, the user guide already explained why Rpi is slow.  They fiddled something but using ***115k baud AT command to do PPPoE is of course slow***.  The service provider might also set lower priority to poor 2G customers

Your board is only 2G GSM/GPRS.  So ***you can not do 3G***.  Bad luck! :(

[image: gsm]

[image: 12345g]

***Update 2019may17hkt1121***

One suggestion is to use something like ***Hologram Nova USB Modem***.  See references below for more details.

***References***

[Raspberry Pi : How to access the Internet using GSM / GPRS Modem (SIM900/SIM800)](https://www.rhydolabz.com/wiki/?p=16325)

[GSM/GPRS TTL UART MODEM-SIM900 - Rhydolabz](https://www.rhydolabz.com/wireless-gsm-gprs-c-130_185/gsmgprs-ttl-uart-modemsim900-p-1076.html)

[Point-to-Point Protocol over Ethernet (PPPoE) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol_over_Ethernet)

[List of mobile phone generations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_phone_generations)

[2G/3G/4G Hologram Nova USB Modem Datasheet](https://hologram.io/docs/reference/nova/datasheet/)

> Hologram Nova is ... open source cellular USB modem, ... with AT
>   command interface.

[Global IoT SIM Card](https://hologram.io/store/global-iot-sim-card/)

> SIM card for global IoT applications, covering over 196 countries,
>   550+ carriers, with flexible pricing:  pay-as-you-go rates or monthly
>   plans

[WaveShare 4G/3G/2G/GSM/GPRS/GNSS (LTE CAT4, for China) HAT for Raspberry Pi US$$66](https://www.waveshare.com/sim7600ce-4g-hat.htm)

[WaveShare GSM/GPRS/GNSS/Bluetooth HAT for Raspberry Pi US$34](https://www.waveshare.com/gsm-gprs-gnss-hat.htm)

[WaveShare GSM/GPRS/GNSS HAT, Compatible with Raspberry Pi 2B/3B/Zeo/Zero W](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/GSM/GPRS/GNSS_HAT)

[WaveShare L76X GPS HAT](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/L76X_GPS_HAT)

[WaveShare GSM/GPRS/GPS HAT User Manual](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Template:GSM/GPRS/GPS_HAT_User_Manual)

[Simple script to use Waveshare GSM/GPRS/GNSS/Bluetooth HAT for Raspberry Pi hat GPS functions](https://github.com/OH1KK/Waveshare-GPS)

[Waveshare GSM/Bluetooth Hat Forum Discussion](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=206761#p1279810)

[Waveshare GSM/GPRS/GNSS HAT not connecting to Cellular network](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90533/waveshare-gsm-gprs-gnss-hat-not-connecting-to-cellular-network)

[WaveShare SIM868 GSM GPRS GNSS Bluetooth HAT for Rpi 2B/3B/Zero/Zero W support](http://SMS%20phone%20call%20CP2102%20UART%20debugging%20-%20US$36)

[Raspberry Pi GSM Module – Mobile Internet (LTE, 3G, UMTS)](https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-gsm-module-mobile-internet-lte-3g-umts/)

> The Raspberry Pi can be connected to the Internet very quickly and
>   easily via the local network. But what if you also need a mobile
>   Internet connection outside your own WLAN? There are GSM modules /
>   Surfsticks (mostly from Huawei), which can be connected via USB.
>   Sometimes are such GSM modules, which support 3G, UMTS and sometimes
>   even LTE, given free with a mobile phone contract which includes an
>   Internet option.
>
> This tutorial shows how to connect Raspberry Pi to the internet using
>   GSM modules.

*- End of Answer -*

Comment: Oh, I understood that. I was wondering why was that. Thank you very much for the explanation.

Is there any option to obtain the internet from such a module except using wifi? I mean to run RPI with the internet as a separate device. I searched for different modules and bought this one but now as explained it is not working with the speed I want :( Any suggestion about an alternative option, please? 

Thanks again!

Comment: @Sachz Have you ever considered  Hologram Nova USB Modem
https://hologram.io/docs/reference/nova/datasheet/ which can do 2G to 4G?

Comment: Nope I haven't. I will go through it. Thank you for the suggestion with the references !

Comment: You are welcome.  Good luck!

Comment: Or try this one? https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-gsm-module-mobile-internet-lte-3g-umts/

Comment: You are welcome.  Have a nice project!